# creating update for a custom module

Tags: database, module, magento-1

My question is about creating update for a custom module extension that I have made.

I have no idea where to begin. So breafly here is what my module does

- It create a database table
- Stores data from a form
- Show them backend in grid

Now the forms have to have more options. but my table dont have enough colums.

**So my question is**

How do i make an update for my module, that update my tables and update the output to my backend grid?

Comment: There is an easiest way: try to google some module creator for magento. It supports database upgrade script creation.

Answer (score 2):

so you have a version in `config.xml`. Something like `<version>1.0.0</version>`.
Replace below `1.0.0` with the version you actually have and `1.0.1` with your version but with the last number incremented.

You need to create the `upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.php` in the same folder you have `install-1.0.0.php`

```
<?php 
$installer = $this;
$connection = $installer->getConnection();
//do this for each column you want to add
$connection->addColumn($installer->getTable('your table name here'), 'your_column_name_here', array(
        'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, //or any other type you need
        'comment'   => 'Column name here',
    ));
```

Then change the version in `config.xml` from `<version>1.0.0</version>` to `<version>1.0.1</version>` and clear the cache.

The upgrade script will add columns to your table and you can continue your work.

Comment: Can i make and package of some sort? I have to make the same change to meny shops